# illogical inequality in Python,C++,C#,F#

Tags: c#, c++, python, math, f#

```
0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3 ==> False
```

I tried this in python, c#, c++, F#, Visual Basic.NET,ASP.NET!

```
0.1 + 0.2 == 0.30000000000000004 ==> True
```

This is True for all languages I mentioned above. Why this illogical inequality happens?

Comment: This is a floating point issue.  Bound to be a duplicate somewhere.

Comment: As you can probably tell, there is no way to store every possible number from 0 to 1.

Comment: You should never compare equality with floating point numbers...  you should always use an AlmostEquals function with an Epsilon value that is determined to be "close enough"

Comment: @chris why? even if that's true, what is the difference between storing 0.1 and 0.2 with 0.3 or 0.4?

Comment: @Kevin, An epsilon generally isn't the best solution, either. ULP is usually more effective than that, but the entire area is tricky.

Comment: @Aidin.T, You have to know the implementation details to know what exactly is different. There have already been some good links posted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python has a decimal library that will allow you to evaluate this to true (while also explaining that why its false as you have it), and in fact, they use almost the same exact example: http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html

> The exactness carries over into arithmetic. In decimal floating point, 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 - 0.3 is exactly equal to zero

Also related, "What every computer scientist should know about floating point", a seminal article written many years ago and still true today: http://www.fer.unizg.hr/_download/repository/paper%5B1%5D.pdf

Comment: So does F# `0.1M + 0.2M = 0.3M`

Answer (score 4):

You might want to give this a read: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html (What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic)

The short answer is that in binary 0.1 is a repeating fraction, it's "somewhere" between 1/8 and 1/16 so there is no 'bit exact' representation of 0.1 (or 0.2).  When comparing floating point values you always have to do so within an epsilon value the prevent such problems.

Answer (score 3):

Read this from the Python docs; it applies pretty much verbatim to all languages:

http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Answer (score 2):

For comparing floating point number, use this pattern:

```
Math.Abs(NumberToCompare1 - NumberToCompare2) < 0.01
```

Where 0.01 is the Epsilon, the precision of the operation.